# fcntl() scope visibility behavior?

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, posix

Is it possible to use `fcntl()` inside a function other than `main()` ? Does the file get unlocked after calling it ? I say this because in this case `fcntl()` and most everything else inside `lockfile()` are out-of-scope when the function `returns`.

```c
int lockfile(void){
    int fd;
    const char *path = "path-to-lockfile";

    struct flock fl;
    fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_len = 0
    fl.l_pid = getpid();

    fd = open(path, O_RDWR|O_CREAT);

    fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl);

    return fd;
}
```

Comment: Read this and thought we we're going to talk about bird flocking behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fcntl` call places a lock on the file. It remains until the file is closed or the lock is released. The structures are only needed to tell `fcntl` what to do.